# Convert a base64string back to byte[]

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I want to use C# to convert a `byteArray` to `base64string` by using `Convert.ToBase64String()`, then I want to send this string to save using MySQL by sending post data to a PHP page. My problem is I can't convert this string back to a `byteArray` using this method as after this string is retrieved from the PHP page (after it got data from MySQL), it tells me that argument on method `Convert.FromBase64String()` was wrong.

I don't where is problem occurs, how can I solve it?

My code:

```
public static string BitmapToString(BitmapImage img)
{
    try
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img);
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        string str = null;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        str = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        return str;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return null;
}

public static BitmapImage StringToBitmap(string str)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        BitmapImage img = null;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(stream);
        return img;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you retrieve the string and attempt to convert back to a byte array?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the string you're getting back from the php page is actually a base-64-encoded string?

Comment: Definitely worthwhile validating that the string data you sent to the database is exactly the same when it comes back.  Depending on your table column definition, it could be padding your string with spaces (e.g., char vs varchar, or nchar vs nvarchar).  Although, I'm not sure if the Base64 conversion methods care or not about trailing whitespace.

Comment: what you should do is call Convert.FromBase64String immediately after the ToBase64String to ensure it's correct (it is)...then that means somewhere along the line it's getting corrupted (it is)

Comment: Ok, seem like some special char was change when it sent to php, did you know how to send data to php without change ?

Comment: Try running it through a HttpUtility.UrlEncode call first.  How are you currently sending the data to the PHP page?

Comment: OK!, problems solved by using UrlEncode method before send data to PHP page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.FromBase64String()` will work for `Convert.ToBase64String()` results but there can be inputs in your aplication which not converted to `Base64String`, those cases might fail.

This is not be a issue with those two methods. Check `Convert.ToBase64String()` result and what you get when you read it from database.

Comment: Ok, seem like some special char was change when it sent to php, did you know how to send data to php without change ?

Comment: OK!, problems solved by using UrlEncode method before send data to PHP page.